# Symmetry of a 3D body

Tags: geometry

I'm having a little blackout about a pretty simple concept.
Does a formal symmetry of 3D rigid body have to be achievable/doable only by literally moving the body with the bare hands (e.g. a wooden cube)?
A reflexion with respect to the mass point of the cube would be a symmetry but it cannot be achieved by rotating the cube. Is that right or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Right, you need a mirror.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *symmetry* in 3D can be a rotation, a plane reflection, a line reflection (180 degree rotation), a point reflection (plane reflection together with 180 degree rotation), or a combination of a rotation and a reflection.

If we want to restrict ourselves to moving with the bare hands, we only have rotations (including line reflections) and identity, which are called *positive* symmetries.

And indeed, the reflection with respect to the mass point (point reflection or *inversion*), cannot be achieved by rotating the cube.

For a cube there are:

- 6 quarter rotations.
- 8 third rotations.
- 9 half rotations (or line reflections).
- 1 identity.
- 9 plane reflections.
- 15 combinations of a rotation and a plane reflection (including point reflection).